# Duplicate each line in VI

Tags: vim

I have a file with these lines:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

I want to convert this into:

```
aa
aa
bb
bb
cc
cc
dd
dd
```

Is this possible in VI?

Comment: Probably of interest for many people getting here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/29368158/812102

Comment: Use atom dude!! :). You can do it with Cmd + Shift + D (or Ctrl + Shift + D)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this simple one:

```
:g/^/norm yyp
```

Yet another one(shorter):

```
:%s/.*/&\r&
```

Another one:

```
:%!sed p
```

Comment: Thanks for the s option, because I was looking to do this for a visual selection and that worked for me.

Answer (score 43):

I like `g/^/t.`  
The `g` (for `global`) command will look for any lines that match a pattern. 

The pattern we specified is `^`, which will match all lines. 

`t` will copy and paste, and finally 
the `dot` tells it to paste below.

Do I win for brevity?

Comment: I like the `g/^/norm yyp`  as it could very simply duplicate or triplicate .. or even more by just adding `p` as needed ... `g/^/norm yypp`  :)  10x

Comment: i liked the accepted answer, more, but upvoted this one, instead, because of the (even small but thoughtful) effort to explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Use the *global command* `g` to operate on every line in the file:

```
:g/^/norm yyp
```

The `g` command will operate on all lines that match a pattern. `^` is a pattern which will match any line. `norm` executes the command `yyp`, which yanks the current line, and pastes it. `:g/^/norm Yp` will also work.

See `:help global` for more details about the command, and see also this [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g) page on `g`.

Comment: @Conner: That doesn't work, as % iterates over the original range, but the command adds lines. You need the "mark first, then iterate" logic of `:global` here.