# How can I duplicate lines matching a pattern, and modify the second line, all in one command?

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I'm trying to add an attribute to a java class, using VIM as the editor.
Therefore I thought I could use a command to ease my work with all the boilerplate code.
Eg:

All lines containing "atributeA", like this one

```
this.attributeA=attributeA //basic constructor
```

should turn into

```
this.attributeA=attributeA //basic constructor
this.attributeB=attributeB //basic constructor
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Way too little information to answer this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having the solution be a one-liner as a requirement seems
a little odd, since you can assign any sequence of
keystrokes or any function or command to a keypress in Vim
if you like.

That being said, this type of thing is Vi's bread and butter. Try:

```
:g/attributeA/ copy . | s//attributeB/g
```

where

```
:g/pattern/ command1 | command2 | ...
```

executes commands on each line matching `pattern` (see `:help :global`),

```
copy .
```

copies the current line (see `:help :copy`) matched by `:g` to after the address `.` (meaning the current line), and

```
s/pattern/replacement/g
```

then performs a substitution on the current line (see `:help :substitute`), i.e. the copy you just made. The `g` flag at the end causes the substitution to be performed for all matching patterns in the line, not just the first. Also note that I left the search pattern empty: Vim will remember the last search pattern used in the previous `:global` or `:substitute` command as a convenience.

Comment: Thanks, it did the job as I Imagined it will.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about 'copy'.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact sample is easy to achieve with:

```
yy
p
:s/A/B/g
```

But it is entirely possible that you want something more generic. If that's the case you should probably edit your question.

Comment: I need something that does that for all lines matching my pattern, not just one.

Comment: `:g/attributeA/norm! yyp:s/A/B<C-v><CR>`

Comment: Thansk for that! It does the copying as I want but it doesn't run the ":s".

Comment: `<C-v><CR>` means "press `<C-v>` then `<CR>` to obtain a literal `^M`".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this function:

```
function AddAttribute()
    exe "/this.attributeA=attributeA;"
    exe "normal yyp"
    exe "s/attributeA/" . input('New attribute: ') . "/g"
endfunction
```

When you call the function `call AddAttribute()` you will be prompted for a new attribute which will be added like in your example. You can bind a key for this with something like `:map <F5> :call AddAttribute<CR>` so you just hit <kbd>F5</kbd> in order to add this line.

## Edit

If you want to duplicate all lines with `attributeA` (which doesn't make sense to me), you could do that with this mapping (`^M` is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
:map <F5> :call inputsave()\|let newAttribute=input('new attribute: ')\|:call inputrestore()\|:g/attributeA/exe "normal! yyp"\|exe ":s/attributeA/" . newAttribute . "/g"^M
```

When you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> you are prompted for a new attribute and alle lines containing `attributeA` are duplicated and substituted with your input.